Exercise: Measure theory and integration
Exercise:
Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(Y,\mathfrak{N})$ be measurable space. Let the family $(\lambda_x)_{x\in X}$ of complex measures on $Y$ is such that the function $X\ni x\mapsto\lambda_x(B)\in\mathbb{C}$ belongs to $L^1(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ for all $B\in\mathfrak{N}$.

Does the function $\lambda_A:\mathfrak{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $\lambda_A(B)=\int_A\lambda_x(B)\,d\mu(x)$ for all $B\in\mathfrak{N}$ and fixed $A\in\mathfrak{M}$, define a complex measure on $\mathfrak{N}$?

$\sup_{B\in\mathfrak{N}}\int_X|\lambda_x(B)|\,d\mu(x)<+\infty$. Is that true?


In the question 1, from the family $(\lambda_x)_{x\in X}$ we form the function $\lambda_A$ defined on $\mathfrak{N}$. This function is finitely additive complex measure but does this function in countable additive in the general case?
In the question 2, we have the Uniform boundedness principle for measures, i.e. Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem, but we can not apply this theorem because we have not that the finitely additive complex measure $B\mapsto\int_A\lambda_x(B)\,d\mu(x)$ is bounded for all fixed $A\in\mathfrak{M}$.

You did not mention whether $\mu$ is a positive measure or complex measure. I will assume without loss of generality that it is a positive measure.
For the first question, fix $A \in \mathfrak{M}$. Recall that a finitely additive measure is countably additive if and only if it is continuous at $0$. See for instance How can I prove that countable additivity implies continuity in zero? . So let $B_n \in \mathfrak{N}$, $B_{n + 1} \subseteq B_n$, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n = \emptyset$. Since $\lambda_x$ is a complex measure, $\lambda_x(B_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ holds for every $x \in X$. By viewing $\lambda_x(B_n)$ as a complex function of $x$, we can break the integral into four parts, each part being a positive integrable function. So assume without loss of generality that $\lambda_x$ is a positive finite measure. We have, by dominated convergence :
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\lambda_A(B_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A \lambda_x(B_n)d\mu(x) = \int_A \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_x(B_n)d\mu(x) = 0
\end{equation*}
We have proven that $\lambda_A$ is a complex measure for every $A \in \mathfrak{M}$.
The claim in the second question is true. Put $A = X$ in the first question and denote the resulting measure $\nu = \lambda_X$. When each $\lambda_x$ is positive and bounded, we have $\lambda_x(B) \leqslant \nu(Y) < \infty$ for every given $B \in \mathfrak{N}$. The general case is the same.

You used monotone convergence for a decreasing sequence of positive measurable functions. This is not true without extra assumptions. However, you can use domonated convergence instead because, by assumption, $x\mapsto \lambda_x(B_1)$ is in $L^1$.

Well, it is bounded above and below. But you are right. Dominated is quicker.

@Jochen I am replying to Jochen's comment so both of you would get notified. I just want to remind you that this topic in measure theory had been giving a little bit more serious impression than such simple proofs. Perhaps, it will be the best for all of us to understand your ideas if you wrote more details at some crucial steps. For example, I don't see how one may apply convergence theorems here, when positive component (like the other 3) of a complex measure $\mu$ can take greater values (in absolute value) at some measurable sets than $\mu$ itself. Please revisit this step.

I am not sure that I understand. The question assumes that  $\lambda_x(B)$ is $L^1$ for every $B$. Therefore, every component must be integrable.

@温泽海 Ok, try to be precise about what the dominant $L^1$ function is. What is the $L^1$ function that dominates all $\lambda_x$ that you used. I may also be wrong here, but I just don't see this dominant function.

@温泽海
I would like to ask you to give a precise step of reduction to the case of a positive function, and after that explain the existence of an integrable dominant.
